# Using conditional formatting to color to a single horizontal gridline in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, conditional-formatting, powerbi-embedded, gridlines

[image: Picture of my issue]

Is it possible to use conditional formatting to color a single horizontal gridline in Power BI?  I just want the 0 horizontal line to be black and the rest to be invisible/removed.

I've tried countless formulas and format styles with no success.  Not sure if I'm missing something simple or not. Is this a limitation within Power BI?

When I try to use the Analytics pane to add a constant line, the only options that appears is "Error Bars"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sgrS.png)

Answer (score 1):

To add a horizontal line at position zero and eliminate other horizontal lines, follow these steps:

1. Turn off the horizontal line from format pane.
2. Go to Analytics pane (right side of format pane) and add a constant line.
3. You can add whatever value/color you want for that line.

**Reference :**

[Use the Analytics pane in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-analytics-pane)

Comment: Thanks, but when I navigate to the Analytics pane, the only option I see is "Error bars" (see the image I added above).  Constant line isn't an option and when I search for it, nothing appears

Comment: Please go through the reference link for limitations and more information.

Comment: This comment answered my question.  Thank you Rahul.